# Turn URL into Anchor tag using Regular Expression

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, anchor, asp.net-2.0

I want the following different input types to be converted into the following anchor tag:

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com    
https://www.stackoverflow.com    
www.stackoverflow.com
```

Replaced with:

```
<a href='http(s)://www.stackoverflow.com' title='Link opens in new window' target='_blank'>www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

I think I could probably write something similar myself, but I'd like to know if there is a standard script for doing this which has been throughly tested?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this function:

```
   Public Shared Function ConvertUrlsToLinks(ByVal msg As String) As String
        Dim regex As String = "((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])"
        Dim r As New Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Return r.Replace(msg, "<a href=""$1"" title=""Click to open in a new window or tab"" target=""&#95;blank"">$1</a>").Replace("href=""www", "href=""http://www")
    End Function
```